# how to use /.cd used in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I define a path named "a" by `pgfkeys` in `tikz`, and add a style named "aa" under this path.

Then I use the style "aa" in `tikzpicture` environment. But I get a wrong message 'Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/aa'.

My code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\pgfkeys{/a/.cd, aa/.style={fill=red}}
\begin{tikzpicture}[/a/.cd]
  \draw[aa] (0,0)--(0,1)--(1,1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This is only an example. I have a lot of styles which will be under the path "a". What's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think there is a slight misunderstanding in what the `/.cd` is doing. If switches the directory in the local group. If you want to make `aa` known also to ordinary `tikz` paths, you can achieve this with the `.search also` key. But then you still need to indicate that `fill` is something under the `tikz` tree. So the following works.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\pgfkeys{/a/.cd, aa/.style={/tikz/fill=red}}
\begin{tikzpicture}[/tikz/.search also={/a}]
  \draw[aa] (0,0)--(0,1)--(1,1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```